# trying to make alpha channel on imported images in WPF transparent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alpha-transparency

I have several PNG images in my WPF app to make buttons. Each of these images has an alpha channel layer with #FF040606 as a color (I didn't design the images so if I'm saying this wrong I'm sorry ahead of time).

I'm trying to make the alpha layer appear transparent like it was designed to do in photoshop.

here is the code I use to set each image as an static image resource:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="backplate" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/ToolBox;component/Images/backplate.png"/>
```

here is the code I use to generate my buttons. How would I make the alpha layer on the PNG image transparent? Every other article I've looked through either does not apply to my situation or is in a different language.

```
<Button Name="BigScreenButton"       
        Background="Transparent"
        Cursor="Hand"
        Visibility="Visible" Margin="17.022,20.001,0,0" ToolTip="Launches a windows designed to be blown up and get attention">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="bigscreenstatic"
                                Source="{StaticResource bigscreenstatic}"
                                Stretch="Fill"
                                Visibility="Visible" />
                        <Image Name="bigscreenhovor"
                                Source="{StaticResource bigscreenhovor}"
                                Stretch="Fill"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <Image Name="bigscreendisabled"
                                Source="{StaticResource bigscreendisabled}"
                                Stretch="Fill"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger   Property="IsEnabled"
                                        Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="bigscreendisabled"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="bigscreenstatic"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger   Property="IsMouseOver"
                                        Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="bigscreenhovor"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="bigscreenstatic"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="bigscreendisabled"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="bigscreenhovor"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```